# Azure AD B2C OpenIdConnect ConfigurationManager error

Tags: c#, identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I have been using IdentityServer with OIDC middleware for asp.net core 2.1 MVC site to have Azure B2C login. To bounce between b2c policies (singin, password reset) I am using custom policy ConfigurationManager. It has been working fine, except from time to time (every few weeks) throws exception in **MergeConfig** method in the PolicyConfigurationManager class. It is very random so you never know when it happens. Recycling the application pool fixes the issue but it happens again after few days or weeks. Any clues?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IdentityServer4.WsFederation.PolicyConfigurationManager.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<MergeConfig>b__0(SecurityKey k)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at IdentityServer4.WsFederation.PolicyConfigurationManager.MergeConfig(OpenIdConnectConfiguration result, OpenIdConnectConfiguration source)
```

PolicyConfigurationManager.cs

```
 class PolicyConfigurationManager : IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>
    {
        private const string PolicyParameter = "p";

        private readonly Dictionary<string, IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>> managers =
            new Dictionary<string, IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>>();

        public PolicyConfigurationManager(string authority, IEnumerable<string> policies)
        {
            foreach (var policy in policies)
            {
                var metadataAddress = $"{authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration?{PolicyParameter}={policy}";
                managers.Add(policy.ToLowerInvariant(), new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(metadataAddress, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever()));
            }
        }

        public async Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration mergedConfiguration = null;
            foreach (var manager in managers)
            {
                var configuration = await manager.Value.GetConfigurationAsync(cancel);
                if (mergedConfiguration == null)
                    mergedConfiguration = Clone(configuration);
                else
                    MergeConfig(mergedConfiguration, configuration);
            }

            return mergedConfiguration;
        }

        public Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken cancel, string policy)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(policy));

            var policyKey = policy.ToLowerInvariant();
            if (managers.ContainsKey(policyKey))
                return managers[policyKey].GetConfigurationAsync(cancel);

            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid policy: {policy}");
        }

      private static void MergeConfig(OpenIdConnectConfiguration result, OpenIdConnectConfiguration source)
        {
            foreach (var alg in source.IdTokenSigningAlgValuesSupported)
            {
                if (!result.IdTokenSigningAlgValuesSupported.Contains(alg))
                {
                    result.IdTokenSigningAlgValuesSupported.Add(alg);
                }
            }

            foreach (var type in source.ResponseTypesSupported)
            {
                if (!result.ResponseTypesSupported.Contains(type))
                {
                    result.ResponseTypesSupported.Add(type);
                }
            }

            foreach (var type in source.SubjectTypesSupported)
            {
                if (!result.ResponseTypesSupported.Contains(type))
                {
                    result.SubjectTypesSupported.Add(type);
                }
            }

            foreach (var key in source.SigningKeys)
            {
                if (result.SigningKeys.All(k => k.KeyId != key.KeyId))
                {
                    result.SigningKeys.Add(key);
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestRefresh()
        {
            foreach (var manager in managers)
            {
                manager.Value.RequestRefresh();
            }
        }

        private static OpenIdConnectConfiguration Clone(OpenIdConnectConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var signingKeys = new List<SecurityKey>(configuration.SigningKeys);
            configuration.SigningKeys.Clear();

            var keySet = configuration.JsonWebKeySet;
            configuration.JsonWebKeySet = null;

            var json = OpenIdConnectConfiguration.Write(configuration);
            var clone = OpenIdConnectConfiguration.Create(json);

            foreach (var key in signingKeys)
            {
                configuration.SigningKeys.Add(key);
                clone.SigningKeys.Add(key);
            }

            configuration.JsonWebKeySet = keySet;
            clone.JsonWebKeySet = keySet;

            return clone;
        }

        
    }
```

startup.cs

```
\\code omitted
string[] policies = new string[] { config_AzureAdB2C_SignInPolicy, config_AzureAdB2C_ResetPasswordPolicyId };

services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Login", options => {
         options.ConfigurationManager = new PolicyConfigurationManager(config_AzureB2C_EndPointForPolicyManager, policies);

//code omitted
})
```

Comment: Please check the private memory assigned to the application pool and the threshold limit for simultaneous threads to be opened and processed.

Answer (score 0):

•   It occasionally sends random ‘outofmemory’ exceptions regarding the ‘MergeConfig’ method of ‘PolicyConfigurationManager’ class because this method is supposed to copy from "other" into "source", however it is copying "source" into "other". Also, once you fix this, you then need to set ‘ValidateIssuer = false’ on your ‘TokenValidationParameters’ inside ‘ConfigureAuth’ method of the Startup class. If you don't, OpenIdConnect will fail because it does not recognize the issuer of the id_token.

•   This will however not fix the ‘OutOfMemory’ exception error, but the issuer’s value returned by the token will not be null as you need to specify either that you do not want to validate the issuer or specify the expected valid issuer inside your ‘TokenValidationParameters’. Thus, this will help you fix the issue that you are facing.

Please find the below link for your reference: -

https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet/issues/3

Comment: Appreciate your input. I can make those changes but setting 'ValidateIssuer=false' has any security flaws? In the link you provided, the issue was reported 6 years ago. Do we have any better approach or alternatives to PolicyConfigurationManager class?

Comment: Yes, the link discussing this issue is surely 6 years old but aptly discusses your condition. Try making those changes and observe, if it gets fixed, then it's ok.